# Can you change an MOV to an MP4 without transcoding?

Tags: video, encoding, mov, mp4

How can change video container from .mov to .mp4 without touching the video itself? Preferably a GUI app.

I have a bunch of videos in .mov and since .mp4 is more widespread I want to use that, but I don't want to lose any quality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do that with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy video.mp4
```

This will just change containers, but obviously will only work with a codec that ffmpeg supports.

Edit: if you absolutely need a GUI, you could use Automator to create a Drag & Drop target, like this:

[image: Automator]

Comment: Already know about this, looking for a simple GUI way of doing it.

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't get any easier than this, but you can use Automator to create a Drag & Drop target. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime 7 Pro.
Again, only if it is in a codec allowed for MP4s.

Answer (score 0):

It is also known as **rewrapping**.

Open the file with [MPEG Streamclip (freeware, adware-free)](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html) and choose `File` > `Save As…`, then choose the format: `MP4`.