# Convert .mov to .mp4

Tags: macos, video, imovie, mp4, mov

I want to convert `.mov` to `.mp4`! I saved the video from iMovie but it is in `.mov` format! How do I convert it to `.mp4`?

I'm using a MacBook and I want to share it to my phone, but my phone can't open `.mov` format video.

Comment: [related](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17727/55266)

Comment: You can do this using iMovie which comes pre-installed on Mac. Follow this article to know the step-by-step guide [Convert on Mac using iMovie](https://www.animaker.com/hub/how-to-convert-mov-to-mp4/#:~:text=in%20MP4%20format.-,Convert%20on%20Mac%20using%20iMovie,-iMovie%20is%20a)

Answer (score 308):

I personally find using `ffmpeg` shell program (available through [Brew](http://brew.sh/) using `brew install ffmpeg`) the most convenient way to do the conversions.

It includes tons of options for nearly any single thing you could possibly do with a movie.

**In your case though, for a conversion, you can simply type:**

**`ffmpeg -i /path/to/input/file /path/to/output.mp4`**

The `.mp4` extension in the output path serves as a cue for the program to do the proper conversion -- no more options are necessary.

Comment: Most of the time you can speed up the process by copying video and audio data instead of transcoding. Like this: `ffmpeg -i /path/to/input/file -c:v copy -c:a copy /path/to/output.mp4` (mov is very similar to mp4 and most of the time contains h264 video and aac audio, which is equally supported in mp4). –

Comment: That's amazing @ernestoche and should be the answer

Comment: `ffmpeg -i /path/to/input/file /path/to/output.mp4` takes more than a minute to convert a 100 MB video, but the mp4 file size is almost 10 times smaller. The command with the `-c:v copy -c:a copy` option converts instantly, however there is no change in file size.

Comment: If you are converting mov to mp4 so that it can be displayed inside a html `video` tag, you can not use @ernestoche 's method, browsers just refuse to play that codec.

Comment: just needs "hours" to download...

Answer (score 32):

You can also use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to convert .mov into several formats:

1. Install and open VLC
2. Go to "File" > "Convert / Stream..."

[image]

3. Load the video (for example drag the .mov file into box)

[image]

4. Choose the format you want
5. Click on "Save as File" button, sit back and relax

Comment: The file will be exported as `.m4v` and not `.mp4`

Comment: @dialex "The primary difference is that M4V files may optionally be protected by DRM copy protection." source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4V

Comment: @dialex rename the file after export.

Comment: In my case the file exported from VLC was slightly smaller than the one I got through Handbrake. I used default settings for both. However, I find Handbrake a bit more convenient to use.

Comment: when i open the file, which made vlc with Quick Time player - it has no audio. (vlc plays it just fine)

Answer (score 27):

## Handbrake

You can use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) to convert `.mov` to `.mp4` files.

> HandBrake is a tool for converting video from nearly any format to a selection of modern, widely supported codecs.
>
> Reasons you’ll love HandBrake:
>
> - Convert video from nearly any format
> - Free and Open Source
> - Multi-Platform (Windows, Mac and Linux)

[image]

Comment: For those that prefer using Homebrew for installation, it is possible to do it using "brew install --cask handbrake" from the command line.

Answer (score 7):

Apple<del>'s gotcha</del> *had ya* covered. ...Sadly, things have changed with the advent of macOS 10.13 High Sierra :\

Once upon a time <del>You can</del> *you could* use **QuickTime Player** to export .mov files and have them converted to .m4v files that will play on your other Apple products. M4V is a video container format developed by Apple from the MP4 standard - M4V is very similar to the MP4 format. The main difference is that M4V supports DRM copy protection - such as for copyrighted material viewed with Apple TV.

[image]

There's also a "Share" option in the player when you open a .mov file in QuickTime Player:

[image]

...and I am not sure if this converts the file, but you can use it to send your video to your mobile device with, for example, the Messages app.

See [this article for more information](https://www.winxdvd.com/resource/m4v-vs-mp4.htm) on the difference between MP4 and M4V.

Lastly, [per this tutorial](http://www.adoreshare.com/imovie-converter/how-to-convert-imovie-video-movies-to-mp4-on-mac.html), you can just Export the file from iMovie:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quicktime no longer has these options in High Sierra. Not sure why Apple removed them.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried converting `.mov` to `.mp4` with both methods.. `ffmpeg` and `handbrake`

input `.mov` file size: 8.6 MB

#### ffpmeg

cmd:

```
brew install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4
```

Output .mp4 size: 1.2 MB

#### Handbrake

download from https://handbrake.fr/
converted using GUI with default settings.
Output .mp4 size: 622 KB

---

Looks like `handbrake` exports with smaller size with no noticeable video quality difference. Also, `ffmpeg` installs tons of dependencies and installation took several minutes.
tldr: I'd go with `handbrake`.

Answer (score 0):

Which iPhone models who you own? The iPhone can only play H.264 or MPEG-4 video. The most simple way is downloading Handbrake, which not only assists you to convert MOV to iPhone suppported H.264 or MPEG-4 video, but also offers advanced profile parameters adjusting function to assist you to get better output video and audio quality.